# Babel object assign plugin in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'd like to use this plugin https://github.com/babel-plugins/babel-plugin-object-assign with https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel. Any idea how should I set that up?

Comment: Why use that instead of `runtime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much like shown in the documentation:

```
babel({plugins: ['object-assign']})
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me with gulp-babel 5.2.0 and babel-plugin-transform-object-assign 6.22.0, I get "The plugin "transform-object-assign" didn't export a Plugin instance".